# Hide row of table depending on variable value

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm pretty new at this so bear with me.

If I have variable "A" = 0, I want to hide the row (preferably collapse the row). The button will at 1 to variable "A" and the row will appear.

```
<body>

<tr id=rowA>
<td>Stat:</td>
<td><span id="Value">0</span></td>
<td><button type="button" id = add onclick="add(1)">+</button>
<button type="button" disabled id = minus onclick="add(-1)">-</button></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
//this button will add 1 to A which is shown
<button type="button" id = minus onclick="add(1)">-</button></td>

</body>

<script>

var A = 0;
    var add = function(valuetoadd){
       A += valuetoadd;


</script>
```

Ignore the value in each cell of the row, but I want to hide the row if A == 0 and if it is >=1 the row will show.

Comment: Humm, could you be a bit more clear. When does this variable A changes to zero? You don't want to monitor it right? If you want to hide the row when "something" happens I can tell you the jQuery for it. Probably you want to define a bit of the skeleton for the add method.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. What is A used for? How is the value A set?

Comment: the row will be hidden by default. when i the user clicks a different button it will add 1 to A. that will then  in turn display the row.

Comment: @Ross - it's more clear now, but I still don't quite get it. You want to click on another button that is not in the table? Please give us html for that button as well if that is the case. which row should it display when clicked on? javascript or jquery?

Comment: a different button? if the whole row is hidden, how would you click the button in the first place. Can you edit the HTML so it's exactly what you want?

Comment: @bitoiu - exactly my thought :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure javascript it will be:

```
if (A==0)
{
  document.getElementById("rowA").style.display="none";
}
else
{
  document.getElementById("rowA").style.display="";
}
```

with jQuery :

```
if (A==0)
{
    $("#rowA").hide();
}
else
{
    $("#rowA").show();
}
```

with jQuery you also can use fadeIn() and fadeOut() functions for smooth transition.